# BubbleChart - Subtract value from radius in array form

Tags: php, arrays, function, oop, svg

I am using the Graph extension of the BubbleChart Class available here:

http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph-misc.php

How i can subtract value from radius (values are in array form) that is taking value from user as taking in "cx" and "cy" ?

Images are available here e.g bubble chart:

http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/HTML/Chart_Working_with_Bubble_Chart_Data.html

The language that i am using is PHP+SVG (scalble Vector Graphic)

```
class  BubbleChart  extends Graph { //from Graph, we are taking Values from user

    function Draw()
    {
        $width = 300; // canvas size
        $height = 400;  
        $value =$this->GetValues();   
        $data=$this->values; 
        $max = count($data); 

        $a="<svg width=\"$w\" height=\"$h\">";

        $sum=array_sum($data);
        for ($i = 0; $i<$max; $i=$i+1) {

            //$a.= "<rect x=\"$value[$i]\" y=\"$value[$i]\" width=\"20\" height=\"$value[$i]\"  style=\"stroke: black; fill:red;\"/>";
            $a.= "  <circle cx=\"$value[$i]\" cy=\"$value[$i]\" r=\"$value[$i]\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" fill=\"red\" />";
            return  $a;

        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand what is the question here. The code you have would work (but for a minimal issue with the variable names).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Do you want to make the circle this draws smaller?

Comment: i just want to subtract the value from r=\"$value[$i]\" from  $a.= "  <circle cx=\"$value[$i]\" cy=\"$value[$i]\" r=\"$value[$i]\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" fill=\"red\" />";

i am making Bubble Chart in SVG+PHP languages

Comment: yup i want to draw circle in different shapes according to user's value